# Password Field not setting when Importing User via Powershell for AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm needing some help with a script I'm working on to import a new bunch of students,
The script seems to work perfectly fine to import the USERS into my AD with all details without any errors despite the fact that the password I'm setting does not work, I have to manually reset the password for each user to actually login to the account.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Prompt user for csv file
$filepath = Read-Host -prompt "Please enter path to your CSV file"

#File path for the CSV
$Users=Import-CSV $filepath

#Initialize the Domain 
$Domain="ABC"

#Loop through each row

ForEach ($user in $Users) 
{

 #Gather user info
 $FName = $user.'First Name'
 $lname = $user.'Last Name'
 $dName = $user.'Display Name'
 $department = $user.'Department'
 $Title = $user.'Job Title'
 $email = $user.'Email Address'
 #$OUPath = $user.'Organizational Unit'
 $userprincipalname = $user.'Email Address'
 $sAMAccountName = $user.'SAMS'
 $pass = $user.'Password'
 $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -force

 #Create new AD user for each user in csv file
 New-ADuser 
-Name "$FName $lname"
-GivenName $FName 
-Surname $lname 
-DisplayName $dName 
-UserPrincipalName $userprincipalname 
-SamAccountName $sAMAccountName 
-Department $department 
-Title $title 
-EmailAddress $email 
-AccountPassword $securePassword 
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $True 
-Enabled $True 
-Path "OU=***,OU=***,OU=***,DC=***,DC=***,DC=***"

 #show output for each user created with the OU
 echo "Account created for $fname $lname $dname $department $Title $email"

}
```

As mentioned the account imports with all details, but when trying to login to the account with the password from the CSV it doesn't allow it, I need to reset the password and only then am I able to login

Any assistance would be appreciated

I have tried changing the code and putting the password variable in after the user import and still did not work.

Tried inputting the below

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $userprincipalname -OldPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "2023!@#" -Force) -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "qwert@12345" -Force)
```

Still wouldnt work

Comment: Make sure the initial password matches domain's complexity requirements.

Comment: Thanks @vonPryz that seemed to have solved the issue.